# Do Ethereum 2.0 ( PoS ) transactions still need to confirm a certain number of blocks?

Tags: transactions, eth-2.0

I tried reading some technical articles but didn't find any ideas.
Can anyone tell me or recommend some relevant technical analysis articles?
Thanks alot!